# Topo To Raster executing but not creating the raster

Tags: raster, arcpy, arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst

I am using **[Topo to Raster by File](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000006t000000)** (ArcGIS version 10.1) via arcpy on a large stream and point dataset. Arcpy runs fine and executes without issuing any error message, however it does not create the raster as it normally does. When I look in the project workspace I can see that the S File that Topo to Raster creates temporarely (before deleting it when execution is terminated) have been created and its size is slightly over 2GB.
Not sure what is the S File used for as it is a binary and can't inspect it.
Is there a limit on the size of the S File created by Topo to Raster?
What can I do to get around this issue in addition to reduce the size of the point dataset?

Note that:
There is enough space in the hard disk thereore the issue is not space; and
The tool runs ok when I reduce the size of the dataset (option which I would like to avoid).

Answer (score 2):

2GB could be the size limit of your raster (e.g. for a tiff file, because ArcGIS does not support bigtif from what I know). Therefore you should work in a file geodatabase.

Note that the number of input points should not affect the output size. You should try with a smaller output cell size as a workaround (arcpy.env.cellSize = your_larger_cell_size)